# MySQL database organization

Tags: mysql, organization, genetics

I have to create a new table in my database. From a form, I'm going to send information to the database:

```
-Gene name
-Chromosome
-Sequence
-Organism
```

On the other hand, I have another table (table 1) with `user id`, `user name` and `password`. So I've thought to create 6 more tables in order to organize that information:

```
-Table2: id_user + id_send
-Table3: id_seq + sequence
-Table4: id_gene + gene name
-Table5: id_chromosome + chromosome number
-Table6: id_organism + organism name
-Table7: id_send + id_chromosome + id_organism + id_gene + id_sequence
```

Do you think that this organization is correct? Or should I change something?

Many thanks to you, people.

Comment: Some of us aren't biologists. Without understanding the inter-relationship of objects we may struggle to help.

Comment: It seems good to me:)

Comment: Give a name to your table if you want more help. For example, I don't understand what `id_send` is.

Comment: Well, the columns with id_something are primary keys...

Comment: The `id_send` information is actually a bit unclear to me, too. Couldn't you simply use `id_user` in Table7?

Comment: Maybe you are right, maybe I should put id_send as primary key in table 7 and delete table 2... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking as recovering biologist....

You seem to be going mad with surrogate keys here - and some of the tables are redundant. Really the database design is not just about how you store information and it's inherent structure but how you intend to access that data - which you've not told us about.

It's far from clear what 'id_send' is supposed to represent.

I suspect (although this is still mostly guesswork) that the structure you need looks more like this:

```
user (user_id, user name, password, PK(user_id))
sequence (sequence_id (auto increment) gene_name, organism_name, 
  user_id, chromosome, PK(sequence_id))
sequence_data (sequence_id, atcgs)
```

Splitting the sequence data from it's metadata facilitates performance and also allows for the possibility that you will have genes for the same organism which have different sequences (although you can change this by adding a UNIQUE constraint on the sequence table.

The following tables allow you to restrict input / apply validation / store additional data about entites which you've not included in your description):

```
genes (gene_name, .... PK(gene_name))
organism (organism_name,.... PK(organism_name))
```